# Why is full compression not used during squash?

Tags: squashfs

Was interested to know why, with space/bandwidth at such a premium, is full compression not used during squash.

For example, calling `mksquashfs` with the `-comp xz -b 1M` options at compression time creates an archive which weighs in at about 80% of the original filesystem.squashfs; yet appears to retain full integrity as both an installation and live image.

Does anybody have some intel here?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably because `xz` (LZMA) compression requires disproportionately more CPU time for both compression and decompression, something that does make a difference when loading the system from a live USB stick, for instance. [See a wider discussion of *xz vs gzip* on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493270/why-is-tar-gz-still-much-more-common-than-tar-xz).

In a similar vein, there is an [open blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-r-dpkg-xz) for using `xz` to compress packages in the Ubuntu archive. This appears to be on hold for the moment on the basis it offers relatively little benefit.

Comment: Interesting.  Can't honestly speak to the contention that xz is a system killer on the unpack side; as even an old single-core Celeron seems to have no problem during install.  Fast & smooth, with a 20% savings in size; but you probably can't do the job with 128Mb of RAM...